# How do I replace a string when using hook_node_view()?

Tags: nodes, hooks

I am trying to use `hook_node_view()` to replace, in the front page, `<div>:placeholder1:</div>` with the content of `$string`.

```
function mymodule_node_view(&$node, $view_mode, $langcode){
  $string = "I am here";
  $node->field_column_second['und'][0]['value']['#markup'] = array(
     '#markup' => str_replace(':placeholder1:', $string, $node->field_column_second['und'][0]['value'])
);
```

I also cleared Drupal cache, but I don't see any change.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you writing this snippet in mymodule.module with mymodule.info existing as well?

Comment: Why do you think `hook_node_view()` would be invoked for the front page too. What did you set as front page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. According to the [doc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7.x), the first parameter should be $node, rather than &$node.
2. The replacement code should look something like this:
   `$node->content['body'][0]['#markup'] = str_replace($old, $new, $subject);` so you missed [0] in your code, when in doubt, do a `dsm($node)` and check the variable you want.
3. Complete code:

   `function test_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode){
       if (drupal_is_front_page()) { // check if necessary
       $string = "new";
       $node->content['body'][0]['#markup'] = str_replace('old', $string, $node->content['body'][0]['#markup']);
       }
       //dsm($node);
   }`

Comment: Can you please check, I edit my question.

Comment: Updated, I believe the value gets displayed comes from $node->content